# Necesito que un campo de la tabla sea igual al numero de id

Tags: php

Estoy resolviendo un sistema en el que necesito por razones de diseño que un campo sea igual al valor del id que toma al momento de insertarse el registro... 
El campo es numerico pero cuando quiero hacer esto me arroja un error:

```
$stmt = $conexion -> prepare("INSERT INTO avisos_comentarios (fecha, idaviso, idpregunta, idrespuesta, idusuario, usuario, comentario, aprobado) VALUES (:fecha, :idaviso, id, :idrespuesta, :idusuario, :usuario, :sDetalle, :aprobado)");
    $stmt->bindValue(":fecha", $fecha);
    $stmt->bindValue(":idaviso", $idAviso);
    $stmt->bindValue(":idrespuesta", $idRespuesta);
    $stmt->bindValue(":idusuario", $idUsuario);
    $stmt->bindValue(":usuario", $usuario);
    $stmt->bindValue(":comentario", $sDetalle);
    $stmt->bindValue(":aprobado", $aprobado);
    $stmt->execute();
```

El idpregunta tiene que ser igual al id del momento de insertar el registro
El error que me arroja es que hay una variable que no está definida... 
si a cada asignación le coloco el : delante y a un determinado campo lo igualo con el id... tendría que andar... o no ?

---

**AMPLIACION**
Es un sistema de preguntas y respuestas alojados en una unica tabla.

[image: esquema de la base]

cuando hacen una pregunta toma el id de la tabla y el idrespuesta = 0 
despues cuando responden la pregunta (tomo el idpregunta) y respondo y en idrespuesta almaceno el id de la tabla... 
Las preguntas tendran distintos id's de usuarios mientras que las respuestas seran del mismo usuario (obviamente) porque es el que puso el aviso...
Obtengo el listado ese haciendo simplemente:

```
FROM [BD] where idaviso = 20 order by idpregunta, idrespuesta
```

una pavada... lo único que necesito es ver cómo duplico ese valor del id... jejejeje

Comment: Por eso mismo que decis, puede llegar a ser un mal diseño. Necesitas control sobre transacciones para que eso no pase. podras explicar que utilidad tiene ese valor?

Comment: amplío la pregunta general, agrego una imagen para ver como funciona

Comment: vas a tener que hacerlo por trigger o despues de guardar actualizar el idpregunta

Comment: no no.. ningun valor duplicado.. lo estas pensando todo mal.. si es la misma tabla, quiere decir que la pregunta ya esta, y que la respuesta es un update a una pregunta existente... no veo porque tenes que repetir nada. pasate mejor por el [chat]

Comment: @MNibor, sigo pensando que es un error de diseño lo que estás sufriendo. Si lo que necesitas es que valgan igual cuando es una pregunta porque los diferencias de una respuesta así, entonces para solkucionarlo basta con que en las preguntas ese campo valga o `null` o `0`. Así buscar preguntas es tan simple como un `WHERE idpregunta IS NULL` en vez de un `WHERE id = idpregunta`.

Comment: Revisa que en tu ->prepare tienes esto **:idaviso, id** y deberia ser :idaviso, :id, ademas de bindearle su valor

Comment: Gracias... Cuando lo resuelva pongo la respuesta